# portal_vocabularies import error

Tags: python, import, plone, portal

I've got this error importing a simple plone site from a different, but identical, instance.

```
2013-07-04 22:21:50 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1372969310.110.695521340475 

http://web009.infoporto.it:8080/manage_importObject
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 620, in manage_importObject
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 642, in _importObjectFromFile
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 358, in _setObject
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 113, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 113, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 113, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
  Module zope.container.contained, line 153, in dispatchToSublocations
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 262, in handleContentishEvent
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 188, in notifyWorkflowCreated
  Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 289, in notifyCreated
  Module Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool, line 635, in _reindexWorkflowVariables
  Module Products.CMFCore.CMFCatalogAware, line 88, in reindexObject
  Module Products.CMFCore.CatalogTool, line 301, in reindexObject
  Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 353, in catalog_object
  Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 476, in catalog_object
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 326, in catalogObject
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 270, in updateMetadata
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 396, in recordify
  Module collective.tourism.archetype.hospitality, line 82, in Description
  Module collective.tourism.archetype.utils, line 10, in Description
  Module Products.ATVocabularyManager.namedvocabulary, line 75, in getVocabularyDict
  Module Products.ATVocabularyManager.namedvocabulary, line 97, in getVocabulary
  Module Products.CMFCore.utils, line 10, in check_getToolByName
  Module Products.CMFCore.utils, line 120, in getToolByName
AttributeError: portal_vocabularies
```

I don't know where to start looking for errors! The destination instance already host 2 running Plone site, so I think it's ok.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like you're using (or were at some point) `products.ATVocabularyManager‎`?

Comment: Yes, I do... it's a problem?

Comment: is it possible it's not installed on the target server? (Seeing how it can't find `portal_vocabularies`?)

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that getToolByName() is failing to look up the ATVocabularyManager tool which lives at /portal_vocabularies in your Plone site.

The first thing I would try is to look in the ZMI, at the top level of your plone site, where you see other tools like portal_catalog, and portal_actions.  If you don't see portal_vocabularies in that list, try uninstalling and reinstalling ATVocabularyManager from the plone_control_panel.